# Commutator estimates between a contraction evolution group and a differential operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, estimation, semigroups, differential-operators, self-adjoint-operators

In the Appendix of "*Commutator Estimates and the Euler and Navier-Stokes equations*", Kato proves the following inequality
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
\|J^s(fg)-f(J^sg)\|_{L^p}\lesssim \|\partial f\|_{L^\infty}\|J^{s-1}g\|_{L^p}+\|J^sf\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^\infty}\,,
\end{equation}
where $1<p<\infty$, $ s\geq 0 $ and $J=(I-\Delta)^{1/2}$.

Now, let $x\in \mathbb{T}\,,$  where $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Given $A_x$ a self-adjoint operator with compact resolvent, we denote by $e^{itA_x}$ the evolution group generated by $A_x\,$.

**Questions:**

1-I am wondering if there exists an inequality of the same type as \eqref{1}, such that we can control the $L^2$ norm of
$$
\|[\partial_x,e^{itA_x}](g)\|_{L^2}\,, \hskip1cm\text{where }\quad [\partial_x,e^{itA_x}](g)=\partial_xe^{itA_x}g\,-\,e^{itA_x}\partial_xg\,,
$$
and $g$ is any function in the Sobolev space $H^s$ for $s>0$ large enough.

2- Or does there exist any estimate on
$
    \|e^{itA_x}g\|_{H^1} ?
$